# How to get GLIBCXX_3.4.14?

Tags: 10.04, libraries

I am trying to use synergy and when I run synergyc or synergys it shows the error:

> synergys: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found
>   (required by synergys)

I don't have that version as shown by this command:

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

**How can I get GLIBCXX3.4.14?** I tried apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-dbg libstdc++6-4.4-dev, but that wont install that version.

Comment: from where are you installing synergys?

Comment: @fossfreedom I downloaded the stable .deb and used package installer.

Comment: possible duplicate here with same error 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found

Comment: why didnt you just do a `sudo apt-get install synergy` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstalled synergy and reinstalled it using Synaptic (Ubuntu Software Center), this time it worked.

```
sudo apt-get remove synergy
sudo apt-get install synergy
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [this link here](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/969/can-anyone-explain-what-to-do-about-glibcxx_3414-not-found-when-starting-synergy)?

*Excerpt from [source](http://synergy-foss.org/osqa/questions/969/can-anyone-explain-what-to-do-about-glibcxx_3414-not-found-when-starting-synergy):*

> Ok, go here -
>   http://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++.so.6%28GLIBCXX_3.4.14%29 , download
>   the file labeled `libstdc++4.6.2-1.fc17.1.i686.rpm` or the 64 bit
>   version. Open it up with archive manager. Open the first folder and
>   copy the next folder over the `usr` folder and you should be set. You
>   might have to be root in order to do this. After that, it should work
>   like a charm...

Comment: Which of those distros releases should I use? Because I don't see ubuntu.

Comment: According to the attached link, you are looking for a file called `libstdc++4.6.2-1.fc17.1.i686.rpm`, that is under Fedora Rawhide. Please follow the source link which is actually a discussion and read it once before trying to install it.